# Why did toString.split(" ") give me a variable that holds 3 mini arrays that each have a length property of 1?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store all of the birthYear values inside an array so I can add them up and calculate the average. I struggle with accessing items and manipulating data from nested arrays and have been working on this for days. I thought things were going well today until I realized that after calling  toString().split(" "); my change variable now holds all 3 birthYears and can console.log them in the format of an array, but stores them each inside a separate array and produces a length of 1 for each of them, instead all of the birthYears being stored in 1 array with a single length of 3.  This confuses me and is problematic because I want to add up all the birthYears and average them, but I'm stuck because I'd planned on doing that by storing the values in a single array (which I thought I could do fairly simply with .split(" "), adding them up and then dividing them by the length of the array to get the average. If anyone can explain why toString().split(" "); behaves this way, or has suggestions on how I can fix it and store all .birthYears in an array ,like so: change = [birthYear1, birthYear2, birthYear3], I'd be very grateful. I apologize for any rambling (this is my first stack post and I didn't want to leave out any important info) and the lengthy code, but I'm not sure how to shorten it.

I stupidly attempted to use the .join() method on variable change to put it all into one string, because I hoped that if I called .split() again after that it would split the way I expected it to but I removed the code because it didn't work.

```js
const myArray = [{
    employee: 'Hanna',
    birthYear: 1997
  },
  {
    employee: 'Zack',
    birthYear: 2000
  },
  {
    employee: 'David',
    birthYear: 1989
  }
];


for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var years = (myArray[i].birthYear);



  var change = years.toString().split(" ");
  console.log(change);



  console.log(change.length) // I'd expected variable change to store all of the birthYear values inside a single array so but it didn't and I'm unsure of how to fix this


};
```

Comment: You're approaching in wrong way, you don't need `split`, just loop through your array add the years and divide by `length of array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
for(let i  = 0;i < myArray.length;i++){
    var years = (myArray[i].birthYear);
```

You are overwriting the variable, and the `years` variable holds the last birthyear when the loop ends.

it should be:

```
var years = [];
for(let i  = 0;i < myArray.length;i++){
    years.push(myArray[i].birthYear);
```

and no need for the further code, now the `years` variable contain all the birth years.

```js
const myArray = [{
    employee: 'Hanna',
    birthYear: 1997
  },
  {
    employee: 'Zack',
    birthYear: 2000
  },
  {
    employee: 'David',
    birthYear: 1989
  }
];

var years = [], totals = 0;
for(let i  = 0;i < myArray.length; i++){
    years.push(myArray[i].birthYear);
    totals += myArray[i].birthYear;
}
    
console.log(years);

var average = totals / myArray.length;

console.log("average", Math.ceil(average));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Array `map()` function to transform `birthYears` into a single array. Then use `reduce()` function to calculate the total.

```
const myArray = [{
    employee: 'Hanna',
    birthYear: 1997
  },
  {
    employee: 'Zack',
    birthYear: 2000
  },
  {
    employee: 'David',
    birthYear: 1989
  }
];

const result = myArray.map(el => el.birthYear);

console.log(result); //[1997, 2000, 1989]

const total = result.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);

const avg  = Math.ceil(total/result.length); 

console.log(avg);//1996
```

Comment: This is half right, op wants to calculate average year so you need to add that part too in your code